# Bootstrap grid output different than expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I have been trying to make this work with bootstrap grid to display my contents but things doesn't work when I try to add certain features to it.
I think I am doing the things right, but since I am new to bootstrap I think I might not know something which the community can help me with.

Here is the code for reference, than I will explain what I'm doing and what I want to achieve. Please don't get scared to see the code, its  very easy to understand, cooperate.

This is my snippet from **base.html**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row"> <!-- 1 -->
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">   <!-- 1 Adding Site Title -->
            <center><h1 class="Heading"><a href="/" style="text-decoration: none !important">Suman Mishra</a></h1></center>
              <hr>
        </div> <!--Closing Col -->
      </div>   <!--Closing Row -->
    <div class="row">   <!-- 2 -->
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
              <center>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="" class="wide" style="text-decoration: none !important">Home</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="" class="wide" style="text-decoration: none !important">Categories</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="" class="wide" style="text-decoration: none !important"> Nothing to display</a> 
                    <li>
                      <a href="" class="wide" style="text-decoration: none !important"> Bhai Kuch bhi</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
              </center>
              <hr>
          </div> <!-- Closing Column -->
      </div>  <!-- Closing Row -->

      <div class="row">  <! -- 3 -->
            <div class="col-md-9">
                {% block content%}
                {% endblock %}
            </div> <!-- Closing Column -->

            <div class="col-md-3"> <!-- 4 -->
               {%block searchbar %}
               {% endblock %}
            </div> <!-- Closing Column -->
      </div> <!-- Closing row -->
</div> <!-- Closing container -->
```

This is my **{% block content %}** which will get place in base.html.

```
{% for post in  posts %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
     <h2 class="mt-4"><a href="/" style="text-decoration: none !important">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
      <!-- Author -->
      <div id="info">
        <p>
          by
          <a href="/authors/{{post.author}}" style="text-decoration: none !important">{{post.author}} </a>  
           | {{post.published_date.date}}</p>
      </div>

      <hr>
      <!-- Preview Image -->
      {% if post.image %}
        <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="Image Placeholder">
      {% endif %}

      <hr>

      <!-- Post Content -->
      <p class="lead">{{post.get_summary | safe}}</p><button class="btn btn-default"><a href="/{{post.slug}}">Read More</a></button>
      <hr>
      <p>Related Topics</p>
      {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <button class="TagButton"><a href="/tags/{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a></button>
      {% endfor %}
      <hr>
    </div>
 </div>  
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And my **{% block  searchbar %}** looks like this.

```
{% block searchbar %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
     <div class="card my-4">
        <h5 class="card-header">Search</h5>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go! 
             </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div> <!-- Closing Card -->
   </div>   <!-- Closing Column -->
</div>     <!-- Closing Row -- >
{% endblock %}
```

My custom css I'm using, **blog-post.css**, rest all is just bootstrap cdn and google font api.

```
body {
  padding-top: 54px;
  font-family: 'Actor',sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 56px;
  }
}

#fb-icon{
    color: #3b5998;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#twitter-icon{
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: #00aced;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#info{
  display: inline;
}

p, a span {
    color: #000;
}

#heading{
  align-items: center;
  font-family: verdana;
  position: relative;
}


#NavBarDummy{
  align-items: center;
  color:black;
  font-family: verdana,'Actor',sans-serif;
}
center{
  position: relative;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline;

}

a{
  color: black;
}

h2 a:hoover{
  color: golden !important;
}

li a {
  width: inherit;
}

.TagButton{
  border-radius: 500px;
}


input[type=text] {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I want my page to look like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OTSZ.jpg
However currently it is looking like this,searchbar is appending below the blog post which it clearly shouldn't. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkN3W.jpg

I have tried to be as clear as possible, added images and comments. Kindly, help.

Edit:
In Comment #1 : I'm making a row and dedicating full width(12 columns) to the title of the website.

In Comment #2 : I'm making another row in which I'm dedicating full width(12 columns) to Navigation bar, which I made myself from li and ul

In Comment #3&#4 : I'm making another row, from which I'm cutting two sections with width 9 columns and other one of 3 columns, the 9 column section should contain my main content of blog post which is nothing but {% block content %} and the 3 column section should contain the searchbar, however the 3 column section is just appending below the 9 column section and not in the same row.

**Edit 2**

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/y2b4upzr/

Comment: please add style also it will explain your code more

Comment: @Anubhavpun Please see the edit, and let me know what else should I add.

Comment: Add Stylesheet.css you are using in your code and you can use snippet to run your code

Comment: @Anubhavpun I have added my custom css, please have a look, I'm looking into how to run snippet, new to community, give me some time until than have a look please

Comment: in <!-- 3 -->try changing col-md-9 and col-md-3 to -xs-

Comment: @MohdTabishBaig Thanks for the input, however it doesn't work, just expanded both post and searchbar. see by yourself. https://imgur.com/a/elxCEWD

Comment: @LightYagmi can you provide fiddle for your code

Comment: @MohdTabishBaig Had a tough time using jsfiddle, hoping it to be clear enough. https://jsfiddle.net/y2b4upzr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

where you linked the Bootstrap CDNs at the top you linked Bootstrap 2 and 4 so I deleted Bootstrap 2.

Second:

You forgot to add the '/' closing the tag at the end of your bootstrap 4 link.

Third: you had too much CSS. I deleted all the CSS from your

Finally:

Your image and your search box need to have their own columns contained in the same row.

```
`<div class="row">
     <div class="col-6>
         <img src='place image url here'/>
     </div>
     <div class='col-6'>
         search stuff here
     </div>
 </div>`
```

[here it is on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chulps/y2b4upzr/2/)

Comment: Wow I guess the answer the answer is here. I wonder how do you figure  it out what which two elements goes in the same row (like here image and searchbar and stuff).

Comment: always remember, when using columns it HAS to be inside a row to work. when the sum of your columns widths equals 12 bootstrap will automatically make a new row

Comment: Hi, Just want to make some things clear, I hope you can help me with some.

Comment: 1. You said bootstrap will make a new row when the sum of columns is 12, I think it makes a new row when the sum is >12 .
2. In my code, I have made a row full dedicated for title, and second row fully dedicated for Navigation bar, these two are working fine. However my 3rd row which are 2 blog posts(see blockcontent) and adjacent to that a column width 3, it shouldn't make any problem, since the sum is 12. Why is the new row assigned ? Also I have included my searchbar as well as blogposts with proper row, it should have worked properly, but it doesn;t work. Kindly help me clear doubts.

Comment: take a look at the bootstrap boilerplate on jsfiddle. I hope this helps you understand. https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap/